# url_encoded_fmt_stream_map not found

Tags: c#, video, xamarin.forms, youtube-data-api

I am using https://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id={videoId} to get url from youtube id.

I am using [this](https://github.com/adamfisher/Xamarin.Forms.VideoPlayer/blob/master/ChillPlayer/ChillPlayer/MarkupExtensions/YouTubeVideoIdExtension.cs) as a reference. But suddenly I started getting `url_encoded_fmt_stream_map` not found. Is there any change in youtube API response ?

Comment: AFAIK `https://www.youtube.com/get_video_info` is not a part of public API ... and you just faced **consequences of using not public API**